# PHP to JavaScript - has time passed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out how to do the following in JavaScript:

```
if(strtotime($row['last_active']) < (time() -(30))) { 
            //update...
        }
```

`$row['last_active']` holds a timedate from MySQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean converting this code from PHP to JavaScript ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what i ment

Comment: It's crazy how many DateTime interval questions have been asked today.

Comment: what is `last_active`?

Comment: last_active holds datetime like this: 2013-03-04 17:33:03

Answer (score 1):

Use a library:

```
var then = new XDate('<?=$row['last_active']?>');
var now = new XDate();

days_between = now.diffDays(then);
```

http://arshaw.com/xdate/

There's also [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/).

You could also, in the query...

```
SELECT last_active, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), last_active) AS days_last_active
```

Or:

```
SELECT last_active, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), last_active) > 30 AS is_inactive
```

The `DATEDIFF()` might require using `DATE()`, too:

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(last_active))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother you with external JS lib, I would do :

PHP

```
<?php 
    $date = strtotime($row['last_active']);
?>
```

JS

```
//Number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
var serverDate = <?php echo (date('U',$date) * 1000); ?>

//Compare with current number of milliseconds (like above) - 30 seconds
if(serverDate < (new Date().getTime() - (30 * 1000)) { 
    //update...
}
```

Comment: I think you've got your variable names mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You Can store `$row['last_active']` in javascript variable and for time you can use javascript current time variable `date = new Date();`

But be aware javascript date variable gives you client machine time not your server time.